# Locking and synchronization using Mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I am creating a program that will run the same function in several processes and several threads so I created a function to achieve locking and synchronization which is

```
HANDLE WaitOnMutex(char* mt)
{
    HANDLE ghMutex=NULL; 
    DWORD lastError=-1;
    do
    {
        ghMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,TRUE,mt);
        lastError=  GetLastError();
        if(lastError!=ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            CloseHandle(ghMutex);
            Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
    while(lastError!=ERROR_SUCCESS);
    return ghMutex;
}
```

and I am using it like the following

```
    HANDLE mtx=WaitOnMutex("Global\\DBG_MY_APP");
    //Do the work that needs sync
    CloseHandle(mtx)
```

Is this a proper way to lock this function ? or do I need to use a different method..

Note: I am using "Global" because some parts of my app is winService and I need to lock between session-Isolated processes

The code is working in testing environment, but I am not sure if I am doing it the right way

Comment: You are using the wrong way. See this documentation for more information. [mutex msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @rbelli can plz tell me what exactly wrong with my way ?

Comment: If I understand exactly what you are doing you are only creating or opening the mutex. You are not getting the mutex. For this, as I see in the example you need to call the function WaitForSingleObjects for check and get the mutex, and then call the function ReleaseMutex to release it.

Answer (score 4):

What you have coded is a busy wait, which is less than ideal under most circumstances. Not only that, but you've wrapped it in heavyweight mutex creation and release calls.

To use a named mutex for cross-process synchronization, each process should call `CreateMutex` only once. You then keep the mutex handle around, and use `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for it and `ReleaseMutex` to release the lock. You can then lock it again with `WaitForSingleObject` next time you need to access the protected resource, and so forth.

When your process is done with the mutex "forever" (e.g. because the process is exiting) then you call `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Nice, but firstly I dont think it is busy wait bcoz of "Sleep(2000);"
but I guess you are right with heavyweight mutex creation.

Now my question is function CreateMutex interruptable ? if so then all my work is wrong if not then my work is bad in performance..

Comment: Admittedly, a 2 second wait is not "busy", but it's still a polling loop, which requires the scheduler to wake up the thread just to check if it can acquire the mutex and then go back to sleep.

Comment: `CreateMutex` cannot "fail" due to scheduling issues unless the other thread/process that creates the mutex changes the access rights so that your thread/process doesn't have the necessary permissions. If that doesn't happen then either your thread creates the mutex, and you get the lock (because you specified the "initial owner" flag as true), or the other thread creates the mutex and you get the handle and an `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` error code, but not the lock.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will sort of work, for a sufficiently loose definition of "work". It's not how I'd do the job though.

I think I'd do things more like this:

Somewhere in one-time initialization code:

```
HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(name); // yes, there are more parameters here.
```

Then to write to the log:

```
WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);

// write to log

ReleaseMutex(handle);
```

Then during one-time shut-down code:

```
CloseHandle(mutex);
```

If you're using C++ instead of C, you usually want to handle this via RAII though, so you'd create a log object that does the `CreateMutex` call in its ctor, and the `CloseHandle` call in it dtor. Then you'd have a write functor that does the `WaitForSingleObject` in its ctor, writes to the log in its `operator()`, and does the `ReleaseMutex` in its dtor. This keeps most of your code relatively simple, and maintains exception safety with little or no extra work.

Comment: Oops -- looks like Anthony beat me to it.

Comment: My new question: is the function CreateMutex interruptable ? if so then all my work is wrong if not then my work is bad in performance..

Comment: I suppose it depends a bit on what you mean by interruptable, but to your code it acts like it's atomic.

Comment: I mean by interruptable that the cpu can be interrupted while executing it, If so another process might enter createMutex while another is executing it that would cause a non-locked situation

Comment: @CnativeFreak: From that viewpoint, yes, it's atomic -- while several processes can hold handles to the same mutex at once, only one of them will own the mutex at any given time.

Comment: @CnativeFreak: You don't get the mutex in the CreateMutex function, but in the WaitForSingleObject function, and release the mutex in the ReleaseMutex function, the code you protect in between this 2 functions.

Comment: You only need to call CreateMutex once, and every time you want to protect your code you call waitForSingleObject and then ReleaseMutex. Then the function that will block will be waitForSingleObject and not CreateMutex.

Comment: You *can* obtain the mutex when you call CreateMutex (that's the second parameter) -- but doing so isn't necessarily the best way to handle things.